# Custom CssClass property: integrate classes with IDE

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I've created a custom WebControl that acts as a container and has a text header. The `CssClass` property applies to the container portion, and I've also added a `HeaderCssClass` property. How do I get Visual Studio to recognize it's a CSS value so the Intellisense will display available classes? I'm guessing there's an attribute I can apply to the property, but I've not had much luck finding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.cssclasspropertyattribute.aspx

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find it, it was added to .NET 3.5, but unfortunately my site is still on 2.0.